# Displaying Values Django Python

Tags: python, django

[image] I am programming in Django 1.4.3 with Python 2.7 on Windows Vista. I am trying to input features for the user such as telephone in `localhost:8000/admin` and then display then on the front web page. I have `index.html`  for the front page:

```
<!-- Shows the label on tab. -->
{% block title %} Inicio - Bienvenidos {% endblock %}
{% block content %} 
<p> Esta es mi primera pagina en Django </p>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> Bienvenido  {{user.username}} </p>
    {% if user.get_profile.photo %}
        <img src="/media/{{user.get_profile.photo}}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.get_profile.telefono %}
        <p> Numero Tel:</p> {{user.get_profile.telefono}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And it is pulling input values defined in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class userProfile(models.Model):

    def url(self, filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
        return ruta

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = url)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

However, after I input the `telefono` (telephone) value, the front page does not display it. I have attached the front page I am getting. The number should appear under the fish fillets image.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the HTML output so we can see what gets rendered?

Comment: Also since you're using Django 1.5, you should know that the `get_profile` method has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#auth-profile-module).

Comment: Hello all. I wasn't editing the proper HTML and PY files. I just migrated my work directory but Notepad++ still had records of those files. Problem solved. The telephone is now displayed. Thanks to all who helped out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the the value commented out. `<!--` and `-->` are considered comments in HTML.

Technically the django template is still rendering the value, since they use a different comment format, but your browser is seeing a comment tag and then hiding the content.

Change this line:

```
<p> Numero Tel:</p> <!--{{user.get_profile.telefono}}</p>-->
```

To this:

```
<p> Numero Tel:</p> {{user.get_profile.telefono}}</p>
```

Comment: @Dombey Oh, OK, can you run `python manage.py shell` from your project root, and load the user's profile to show us what `user.get_profile.telefono` outputs?

Comment: @Dombey After you've loaded up your shell, you'll want to do `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, and load the specified user object. From your original post, it looks like your username is root, so doing `user = User.objects.get(username='root')` will fetch your user. Then you can run `user.get_profile.telefono`.

Comment: Did that and got `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'telefono' .

Comment: @Nitzle Got `u'88888-8888-8888` which is what I entered but it is still not displaying on the front page.

Comment: @Dombey See Ric's answer. Maybe you can also post the code from `views.py` in your original question so we can see how you render the template?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you are editing the page you think you are editing. Change the first line of content to:

```
<p> Esta es mi segunda pagina en Django. {{user.get_profile.telefono}}</p>
```

And make sure the text changes to segunda.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't editing the proper HTML and PY files. I just migrated my work directory but Notepad++ still had records of those files. Problem solved. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

To get user extended information:

```
View = request.user.get_profile().field_name
Template = user.userProfile.field_name
```

So to display user extended information in template, it must be

```
{% block title %} Inicio - Bienvenidos {% endblock %}
{% block content %} 
<p> Esta es mi primera pagina en Django </p>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> Bienvenido  {{user.username}} </p>
    {% if user.userProfile.photo %}
        <img src="/media/{{user.userProfile.photo}}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.userProfile.telefono %}
        <p> Numero Tel:</p> {{user.userProfile.telefono}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```